# Step by step instruction to create multiport socket.io server using node.js

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io, socket.io-1.0, socket.io-redis

can someone help me with step by step instruction about creating multiport socket.io node.js server?

My current situation, I have 1 server of socket.io node.js with 1 port to serve hundreds of client. For about 1 year, the number of users connected is maximum 400 users. I suspect this maximum number cant be increased due to number of server which is only one.

I want to increase the number of server and I found an article http://socket.io/docs/using-multiple-nodes/ but I cant implement it because its too theoritical for me. My knowledge about server is too little for it.

Please help me to implement it step by step. Tools I have now: a putty that can connect to centos VPS server which stores all the coding for working applications built on node.js, php, etc.